Kiel nomu diversajn kategoriojn de aŭtoj por transporti homojn?
Miakomprene ekzistas laŭgrande kvar ĉefaj kategorioj de aŭtoj por transporti homojn (ĉiuj bildoj el Vikipedio).
kategorio 1

Kiel vi nomas ĉi tiun kategorion? Ĉu "pasaĝera aŭto", "personaŭto" aŭ...?
kategorio 2

Mi guglis tion, kaj montriĝis, ke eksistas pluraj nomoj por ĉi tiu kategorio. Mi trovis "furgoneto", "buseto", "tegmentaŭto", "grandspaca aŭto".
Ĉu ne "furgoneto" estas franclingvaĵo, kiu ne tuj estas komprenebla al alilingvanoj? Plie BonaLingvo.net konstatas, ke furgon·o → ŝarĝ·vetur·il·o, kamion·et·o. Se furgono egalas kamineton, kio estas furgoneto? Ĉu "eta kamineto" aŭ "kamineteto"? Al mi ŝarĝveturilo sonas ne taŭga, ĉar tia aŭto estas por transporti homojn, ne ĝeneralan ŝarĝon.
Ĉu ne "buseto" intermiksas kun la kategorio 3?
Certe povas aŭtoj de aliaj kategorioj ankaŭ havi tegmentoj.
Ĉu vi tuj komprenas la nomon "grandspaca aŭto"?
kategorio 3

Ĉu ne simple "buseto"?
kategorio 4

Ĉu ne simple "buso"?

Estas pluraj duboj en la sama demando, malfacilas respondi ilin ĉiujn do mi nur sugestos kion ni uzas familie, espereble tio helpos iel:
aŭto: persona aŭto. Por la aparte etaj, se bezonatas, ni aldonas adjektivon (dupordan, dulokan, senkofrujan,...)
kamioneto: eta kamiono (aŭ granda aŭto) kiu ne havas kofrujon, ĉar la tuta ne homa parto estas destinita al portado de ŝargoj.
buseto: ĝi povas esti samgranda kiel kamioneto, sed ĝia ĉefa tasko estas porti personojn. Nombra adjektivo donas la grandon: sespersona aŭto sesloka, dekpersona,...). La vojaĝon rektan inter hoteloj kaj flughavenoj faras ofte tiaj veturiloj.
buso: ĝi portas kelkdekon da personoj. Ĝi cetere ofte sekvas antaŭdifinitan vojon. Miaopinie ili devus povi porti pli ol dekdu personojn. Ĝi povas esti unu aŭ duetaĝa.
Mi neniam aŭdis aŭ legis la vorton furgono. Mi samopinias kun La bona lingvo, ĝi ne bezonatas.
Por normala nefaka uzo aŭt-, kamion- kaj bus- simple kaj internaciece kovras ĉion. Kelkaj aliaj adjektivoj (aŭ elementoj de kunmetaĵo): sesrada, frostiga, kvaraksa,...
